# Trying to run an animation of a view on top of ARSCNView

Tags: ios, swift, augmented-reality, arkit

I'm trying to run an animation on top of my ARSCNView but the animation part is hidden and the view appears once the animation is finished. The code i'm running is

```
guard let phoneIcon = self.phoneIcon else { return }

UIView.animate(withDuration: 5.0, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0, initialSpringVelocity: 0, options: .curveLinear, animations:
{
  phoneIcon.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 40.0, y: 40.0)

}, completion: nil)
```

Phone icon is just a view laid on-top of the ARSCNView in the view controller. Is this a threading issue related to the camera running in parallel to the animation?

Comment: You aren't supposed to cover an AR or SCN scene view with anything.

Comment: @ElTomato then how are you supposed to exit the view or display messages?

Comment: Ask not what UIView can do for you.  Ask what you can do for UITouch.